# UISearchBar resignFirstResponder not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uisearchbar

`UIViewController` needs to hide keyboard inside `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear` methods. `UIViewController` stays in memory after disappearing and can be presented again. On first appearance `UISearchBar` is not `firstResponder` and keyboard is hidden. But if I pop `UIViewController` with keyboard shown and then push it again - keyboard is not hidden, however I call:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    instrumentsTableView.register(UINib(nibName: kDealsFilterInstrumentTableViewCellNib, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: kDealsFilterInstrumentTableViewCellReusableId)
    instrumentsTableView.dataSource = self
    instrumentsTableView.delegate = self
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    if presenter.numberOfInstruments != 0 {
        instrumentsTableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: false)
    }
    KeyboardManager.shared.unsubscribe()
    instrumentsSearchBar.text = ""
    presenter.findInstruments(with: "") //just sets settings to default/ reloads data


    instrumentsSearchBar.endEditing(true)
    instrumentsSearchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    view.endEditing(true)
    view.resignFirstResponder()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    KeyboardManager.shared.subscribe(self)
}
```

`KeyboardManager` - sends notification if keyboard's state has changed, if relevant:

```
final class KeyboardManager {

    private init() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    static let shared = KeyboardManager()

    @objc private func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let keyboardSize = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
            let height = keyboardSize.cgRectValue.height
            keyboardHeight = height
            keyboardState = .shown
        }
    }

    @objc private func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
        keyboardHeight = 0
        keyboardState = .hidden
    }

    private weak var subscriber: KeyboardManagerDelegate?

    func subscribe(_ delegate: KeyboardManagerDelegate) {
        subscriber = delegate
    }

    func unsubscribe() {
        subscriber = nil
    }

    private var keyboardHeight: CGFloat = 0

    private var keyboardState: KeyboardState = .hidden {
        didSet {
            if keyboardState != oldValue {
                subscriber?.keyboardDidChange(state: keyboardState, height: keyboardHeight)
            }
        }
    }
}

enum KeyboardState {
    case shown
    case hidden
}

protocol KeyboardManagerDelegate: class {
    func keyboardDidChange(state: KeyboardState, height: CGFloat)
}
```

I've tried to use this code inside `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear` - but `UISearchBar` is still `firstResponder`. If I pop with keyboard being hidden - it stays hidden. What might be the problem?

**Screencast:**

[image]

[Sample project with the same issue on bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/JuicyFru1t/uisearchbar-resignfirstresponder-bug/overview)

Comment: Can you share GIF

Comment: Are you using a UISearchController? Then just call `searchController.isActive = false` in `viewWillDisappear` it will dismiss the search bar.

Comment: @fl034 no, I am using `UIViewController` with `UISearchBar`

Comment: Try resigning search bar before poping viewController.

Comment: @Krunal check imgur link

Comment: @Anuraj I've tried to call these methods inside `viewWillDisappear` - result is the same, although I can see keyboard hiding animation, but when I push again - it is shown

Comment: @JuicyFruit Have you written searchBar.becomeFirstResponder() in viewWillAppear ??

Comment: @Krunal check changes

Comment: @JuicyFruit Can you try writing "KeyboardManager.shared.unsubscribe()" after     "instrumentsSearchBar.resignFirstResponder()"

Comment: @Anuraj I even removed KeyboardManager. Nothing changed.

Comment: @Krunal I've created an empty project, which only has an `UIButton` to push and 2 `UIViewControllers`, problem still exists

Comment: @Krunal check changes, link added

Answer (score 2):

For keyboard issue this will work fine,

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
```

Write this in `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear`

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code: [Sample project with the same issue on bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/JuicyFru1t/uisearchbar-resignfirstresponder-bug/overview) and its working as expected and fine.

Here is that code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func btnShowSearch(button: UIButton) {
        if let search = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SeachBarViewController") {
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(search, animated: true)
        }
    }

}

// SeachBarViewController
class SeachBarViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        attemptToHidKeyboard()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        attemptToHidKeyboard()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        attemptToHidKeyboard()
    }

    override func didMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?) {
        if parent == nil {
            attemptToHidKeyboard()
        }
    }

    override func willMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?) {
        if parent == nil {
            attemptToHidKeyboard()
        }
    }


    private func attemptToHidKeyboard() {
        self.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
        self.view.resignFirstResponder()
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Here is result:

[image]

Comment: can you specify iOS version of simulator? you didn't change any code?

Comment: and you didn't change code of rootviewcontroller, where I store controller with SearchBar? If so, it must be fixed already, because it does not behave like this on iOS 11.2 and iOS 10 build with Xcode 9.2

Comment: I used your storyboard and SearchBarController file. Nothing else... And it works. I've Xcode 9.2 also. Let me check the same with Xcode 9.2

Comment: your code is not the same. check my `RootViewController`, I want to store `SearchViewController`, not initiate it on button click